# How do I determine compatibility between .NET Framework and .NET Core versions?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm working on a .NET solution. This solution has several .NET Core 3.0 libraries. This solution also features an XUnit class library that is .NET Framework.

When I choose .NET Framework 4.7, it complains that it is not compatible with .NET Core 3.0 libraries. However, if I change the class library to .NET Framework 4.6, it is then compatible with .NET Core 3.0.

How do I keep track of compatibility between .NET Framework and .NET Core versions?

Comment: `xUnit` is .Net Core.

Comment: which libraries, normally it is .net standard that is compatible with .net framework or core check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best lens to view this thru is the .NET Standard. .NET Standard 2.0 is really the most compatible between .NET Core and the .NET Framework starting in 4.6.1. [The docs site provides a nice matrix of compatiblity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).

xUnit in most parts targets .NET Standard.

If you target your class library as .NET Standard 2.0 - it should work on the .NET Framework, .NET Core 2.1 or .NET Core 3.0 or anything moving forward. With a .NET Standard library, you shouldn't be able to reference non-.NET Standard libraries/projects.